# Laravel eager loading with() not working with custom columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following relationship in my `Component` model:

```
public function subComponent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubComponent::class, 'code', 'code');
}
```

Both have a column called `code` with data type string. One example for a code would simply be "*AB1234*".

I try to load components together with their sub components based on this code:

```
Component::with('subComponent')->get();
```

Now a few records are not loaded with their resceptive component for some reason. The interesting part is that is is working if I do not eager load it:

```
Component::where('code', 'ABC1234')->first()->subComponent;
```

But this only happens to specific sub components. Most of them can be eager loaded and I cannot find a reason why others are  not loaded. I have activated https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to investigate what happens in the background but it seems absolutely correct:

```
select * from `components` where `code` = 'ABC1234' limit 1;
select * from `sub_components` where `sub_components`.`code` in ('ABC1234');
```

If I execute the second statement it is giving me the proper result. But it is not applied to the component collection. **This behaviour does not apply to all components. Most of them do eager load their sub component. But some others have this described odd behaviour. I cannot find the reason why.**

Comment: Are you sure the codes are completely identical? They might contain invisible characters.

Comment: Yes 100% sure. If I execute the same eager loading statement in the database the record is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is due to your relation declaration.
When you declare this :

```
public function subComponent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubComponent::class, 'code', 'code');
}
```

It means that your `Component` belongTo a `subComponent`. I think it is the opposite. You should redeclare your subComponent relation like this :

1. If `Component` **--HasOne-->** `SubComponent`

```
public function subComponent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SubComponent::class, 'code', 'code');
}
```

2. If `Component` **--HasMany-->** `SubComponent`

```
public function subComponent()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubComponent::class, 'code', 'code');
}
```

This fix should solve your problem.